# "InvalidArgumentException: Field field_participant_email is unknown" although it exists

Tags: 8

We're working on a custom module where we are creating participant content types programatically. We then have some queries to check for where a participant exists.

However although the field `field_participant_email‎` exists and is defined, the below code results in the error `InvalidArgumentException: Field field_participant_email is unknown`.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'participant');
$query->condition('field_participant_meeting', $meeting_id);
$query->condition('field_participant_email‎', $email);
$ids = $query->execute();
```

We've tried clearing cache, deleting and re-adding the field to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions or experiencing with this type of issue?

Much appreciated.

**Update 1**

For clarity, I've also checked the following:

- checked the spelling of the field
- deleted all the content types and reinstalled them through features
- tried `$query->condition('field_participant_email‎_value', $email);`
- tried `$query->condition('field_participant_email‎.value', $email);`

**Update 2**

Looking into the `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/QueryInterface.php` interface documentation, it seems that adding a condition against a custom field is not supported. This would explain why the error occurs. However I'm yet to find an alternative. I've also experienced the same error when trying to set the value of the field `$node->set('field_participant_email‎', 'name@domain.com');`.

Comment: From a technical level, there is no difference in custom fields - a field is a field, whether you created it yourself, or it was contributed by a module, or part of core, so your comment on the documentation isn't making sense.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the field condition(s) is missing a column name (and potentially an operator)

`$query->condition('field_participant_email‎.value', $email, '=');`

Here is a useful tutorial on Entity Queries for Drupal 8 I always refer to:

[The Drupal 8 version of EntityFieldQuery](https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-version-entityfieldquery/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This unfortunately did not resolve the issue and threw another exception. Having read that article you shared I suspect the dot notation works when navigating entity references. The new exception thrown btw was `Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumns() on boolean in /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php on line 232`